# Why there is no description in model file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Java background. New to RoR
When I use the cmd:

```
rails g model User name:string
```

I create a model named User and it got attribute name as type of string. But when I look up the models/user.rb, the only code I found is:

```
    class User< ActiveRecord::Base
    end
```

so I guess this user.rb file is not used for defining the User class, so what's it for? And where is the file defining the class? where should I put constructor and methods for class?

Comment: You found the `Article` class in the `user.rb` file?

Comment: I suggest you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Open User.rb rather than Article.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did find the right class.

One of the reasons why Rails is so awesome is that, unlike java, you do not need to explicitly add getter/setter methods to your class.

This, and many other standard things are done for you automatically by Rails, in the background. You really should read the Rails Guides to see what else Rails does for you. You will find that you need to do a lot less of the kind of regular, manual settings that you have gotten used to.

Answer (score 3):

The getter and setter methods for the columns you have defined on the users table (and a whole lot more) are generated by ActiveRecord::Base on your behalf.

You'll find that you can instantiate a new user and assign a name to it without writing the code to do so yourself.

From the rails console:

```
user = User.new
user.name = "George"
user.name
user
```

Answer (score 2):

In rails, the model is used primarily to hold **database validations** and **helper methods**, check your `db/schema.rb` to find specific attributes of your models (i.e columns in your tables). To update your schema you'll use [**migrations**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

But yeah, reading this will help a lot: http://guides.rubyonrails.org